# Angular SCE trust HTML variable in rootScope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to pass a variable from an Angular scope function, such that the HTML contents of a TinyMCE `textarea` are rendered in an `ng-bind-html`. Unsure why the following functions are still getting `$sce.unsafe` error

**rootScope**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $sce, $compile) {
    // Text Parsing
    $rootScope.txtRefresh = function(obj) {
      obj = $sce.trustAsHtml(obj);
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.txtRefresh = function (obj) {
  $rootScope.txtRefresh(obj);
}
```

**Partial**

```
<label>Paragraph 1</label>
<textarea data-ui-tinymce ng-change="txtRefresh(field['txt-1'])" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field['txt-1']" rows="4" placeholder="Description..." />
<div ng-bind-html="field['txt-1']"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function to trust the resource directly in the binding. So: `txtRefresh(field['txt-w']`

$sce.trustAsHtml returns a trusted resource, it does not modify the string passed to it. Therefore, your ngChange isn't doing anything meaningful. You could alternatively call a function on changes that trusts the value in `field['txt-w']` and stores it in the scope, and then have ng-bind-html use that new trusted value.

Comment: also needed to switch `txtRefresh()` function to `return obj;`